# Android:java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed

Tags: android, database

I am making an android database app in which when i fetch values from database using cursor
It gives me the following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
```

I am using the following code  for fetching:

```
 public Cursor fetchChildren(String KEY_){

           Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT children FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE_NAVIGATION
                   + " WHERE key_ = ?", new String[] {KEY_});
               return c;
           }



     try{   
     for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
       db.open();
     System.out.println("children are");
      Cursor cursor=db.fetchChildren(keys_a);
      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) // data?
            {
        System.out.println( cursor.getString(9)); 
     }
    }
 db.close();
    }
   catch(Exception e)
  {
  System.out.println(e);
      }
```

Comment: Why are you opening `db` for every iteration?

Comment: even if i dont open it it is giving me the same exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `System.out.println( cursor.getString(0))` instead of `System.out.println( cursor.getString(9));`

Or use `System.out.println(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("children"));`

***Problem in your logic:***

*You are fetching single column from your data base. So cursor having only one column (children).* As you know that column index starts from 0 (0 for first column, 1 for 2nd column ...), you have to pass 0 in `getString()`. Alternate way is, to search column index in cursor and pass that with `getString()`. as [getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex%28java.lang.String%29) calculate the index of column name in cursor, and use it within [getString(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString%28int%29).

Hope this will help.